# Function overloading between anonymous namespace and named namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, overloading, name-lookup

Is this not allowed? Can someone please explain why?

### Algorithms.h

```
namespace Algorithms
{
  int kthLargest(std::vector<int> const& nums, int k);    
}
```

### Algorithms.cpp

```
#include "Algorithms.h"
namespace
{
int kthLargest(std::vector<int> const& nums, int start, int end, int k)
{
   <implementation>
}
} // end anonymous namespace

namespace Algorithms
{
   int kthLargest(std::vector<int> const& nums, int k)
   {
      return kthLargest(nums, 0, nums.size() - 1, k);
   }
} // end Algorithms namespace
```

The error I run into is:

```
> /usr/bin/c++   -I../lib/algorithms/inc  -MD -MT
> lib/algorithms/CMakeFiles/algorithms.dir/src/Algorithms.o -MF
> lib/algorithms/CMakeFiles/algorithms.dir/src/Algorithms.o.d -o
> lib/algorithms/CMakeFiles/algorithms.dir/src/Algorithms.o -c
> ../lib/algorithms/src/Algorithms.cpp
> ../lib/algorithms/src/Algorithms.cpp: In function ‘int
> Algorithms::kthLargest(const std::vector<int>&, int)’:
> ../lib/algorithms/src/Algorithms.cpp:70:50: error: too many arguments
> to function ‘int Algorithms::kthLargest(const std::vector<int>&, int)’
> return kthLargest(nums, 0, nums.size() - 1, k);
```

Comment: Note that std has [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code leads to recursion call. When `kthLargest` is called inside `Algorithms::kthLargest`, the name `kthLargest` will be found at the namespace `Algorithms`, then [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) stops, no further scopes (e.g. global namespace) will be examined. After that, overload resolution is performed and fails because arguments don't match.

You can change it to

```
namespace Algorithms
{
   int kthLargest(std::vector<int> const& nums, int k)
   {
      // refer to the name in global namespace
      return ::kthLargest(nums, 0, nums.size() - 1, k);
      //     ^^
   }
}
```

or

```
namespace Algorithms
{
   using ::kthLargest;  // introduce names in global namespace
   int kthLargest(std::vector<int> const& nums, int k)
   {
      return kthLargest(nums, 0, nums.size() - 1, k);
   }
}
```